# Energy functional

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mathematical-physics, ricci-flow

During my study on Ricci Flow I faced some functional known as enery functional. For example Einstein-Hilbert functional is called an energy functional, also in Perelman's works $\mathcal{F}(g,f)=\int_M(R+|\nabla f|^2)e^{-f}d\mu$ is introduced as an energy functuional, where $M$ is a closed manifold, $g$ is Riemannian metric, $R$ is Ricci scalar, and $f$ is any function that in the physics literature is called **dilation**.

I do not know why these functionals are attributed to the energy concept and why does $f$ show dilation concept?

Can anyone help me? Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Cross-posted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61866/2451